# Weak markov property question

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I have a doubt concerning the definition of Weak Markov Property:

Weak Markov Property: For every initial distribution $\mu$ and every $(X_1, ... , X_n)$ we have

$E_\mu (h(X_{n+1},X_{n+2},...) | x_0, x_1, ..., x_n ) = E_{x_n} (h(X_1,..., X_n) )$
provided the expectation exists.

My textbook says that, when $h()$ is the indicator function, this property boils down to the very Markov chains definition property, i.e. $P((X_{n+1} | x_0, ... , x_n )=P(X_{n+1} | x_n )$

I see that if $h() = 1_A () $ then
the weak markov property gets $P_\mu ((X_{n+1},X_{n+2},...) \in A | x_0, x_1, ..., x_n ) = P_{x_n} ((X_1,..., X_n) \in A)$, but I am not sure how to go from here to $P((X_{n+1} | x_0, ... , x_n )=P(X_{n+1} | x_n )$. Can someone help?

Thanks!